# IllegalAccessException: can not access a member of class com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ManifestProcessorTask

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Android studio keeps telling me that the build has failed. I am not using Kotlin and all my code is in JAVA. I keep getting this error ONLY when i want to build/run the project. I always need to delete .gradle folder and restart Android studio to get this working again. It's not an IDE issue i feel as I have used both IDE version 3.1 and 3.3. I have also updated Kotlin to the latest version currently 1.2.70

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not create task ':app:processProdDebugManifest'.
   > java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.FunctionCaller$FieldSetter can not access a member of class com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ManifestProcessorTask with modifiers "private"


ext.kotlin_version = "1.2.70"
```

After a complete restart and invalidating cache the build succeeds, but after any new changes i make it cant build again until i restart the entire IDE and delete the .gradle folder

here are my root Project version numbers

```
ext {
    // SDK and tools
    minSDK = 18
    targetSDK = 28
    compileSDK = 28
    buildTools = '28.0.2'

    // SUPPORT LIBRARY
    SupportLibrary = '28.0.0-rc02'

    // Debug the App
    debugMode = true
    minify = true
    proguard = false
    multidex = false

    // App Versioning
    versionCode = 7
    versionName = 0.7
}
```

Comment: Is the version of your gradle plugin in your project's `build.gradle` the latest?

Comment: This is what I have at the moment 

`dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha11'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }`

Comment: try changing `'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`  to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'`

Comment: Yes when I do that then I get the Firebase App not initialized Error yet i call 
`FirebaseApp.initializeApp(LoginActivity.this);` as the first thing, the build works but the app keeps crashing due to firebase

Comment: Ok, I kinda fixed my Firebase Initialization issue like this, i guess now we have to manually do this as follows:  
`FirebaseOptions.Builder builder = new FirebaseOptions.Builder() . 
                .setApplicationId("APP_ID") . 
                .setApiKey("API_KEY") . 
                .setDatabaseUrl("DB_URL") . 
                .setStorageBucket("BUCKET_NAME");  `

Answer (score 7):

Every time this problem occurs, I restart / invalidate the cache and the problem is resolved.

File > Invalidate Caches/Restart... > Invalidate and Restart

Comment: Just FYI, I'm not saying this won't work, but I get this error with CI (Bamboo) which does not use Android studio, and currently use `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha10'`. It also only seems to be a temporary fix as the problem comes up again (in Android Studio) after a while.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by updating to Android

**Studio 3.3 Canary 11**
Build #AI-182.4323.46.33.5012296

Make sure to update the gradle as well. A pop up will prompt on your first boot after the update.

Comment: It WORKED! yess! Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 1):

If you using the alpha gradle build tool

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha10'
```

then downgrade to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in gradle version 3.3.0-alpha13 which can be fixed by upgrading you gradle version.

To fix this issue, upgrade your gradle version in project level build.gradle

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0-alpha01'
```

Original answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52965104/3948854

Comment: Didn't work, even not works in `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0-alpha02'`