# Studio Error : Class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.FunctionCaller$FieldSetter

Tags: android, android-studio

> Class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.FunctionCaller$FieldSetter can not
>   access a member of class
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ManifestProcessorTask with modifiers
>   "private"

Already tried below approach

1. Delete all .gradle files and invalidate/restart studio
2. Rebuild project
3. Update kotlin

But after restarting studio this error comes after every few successful builds.
I am using Android Studio 3.3 Canary 12 and gradle version 3.3.0-alpha12.

Comment: Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Kotlin Updates -> Update channel -> Early Access Preview/Stable -> Update -> Restart

Comment: Already mentioned above this issue remains after updating kotlin as well.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is resolved in gradle plugin version **3.4.0-alpha01**.

To fix this issue, upgrade your gradle version in project level build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0-alpha01'
```

Comment: this didn't work for me; was already at 3.4.0-alpha01 & I still get this error.

Comment: How does this fix the problem?

Comment: Didn't work, even not works in 
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0-alpha02'`.

Comment: Not a solution but it worked for me. Restart the Android Studio and build/run the project again.

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0-alpha01'
```

in your project gradle

Answer (score 0):

Closing down Android Studio and restarting worked for me